# Room database in a multi module project

Tags: android, android-room

In my project, I have an `app module` with the '`app`' name and an `Android Library` called '`app_lib`'. I want to have a `database` that both work with this `database`.

> The question is, how can I do this?

I've done my job so far, I've made my `models` and `Dao's` `classes` in the '`app_lib`', and I've called in the `abstract class database` in the '`app`' and `created tables` in this way. Now, the question is, how do you do in the '`app_lib`' `Call the queries`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating AppDatabase:

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Second parameter is the name of the database, if you give same name in both modules, it should use same database, provided that they are part of the same application.

You should not import models and dao from your app module. Your app module should be dependent on the library not the other way around.

*However*, if you don't want to copy over same class files to both modules, you could either move your room classes to the library and import those classes from lib module. If you don't want those classes to be part of lib module, you can create another module that handles database operations and then use classes from that module in both the library module and the app module.

Comment: Move the room implemention to another module, I will need create a migration for it?

Comment: @WellingtonYogui no, migrations are for different versions of same *database* not modules

Comment: @WellingtonYogui just create the classes in separate module

Comment: @Zohaib Amir I learned a lot from your answer, but still have a question. If there are multiple modules to add or change tables, how to upgrade the database？

Comment: @leimenghao by upgrade you mean you want to change/update a table? Ideally, you should not be changing database directly from the modules, one separate module for handling database operations should be used in all modules. This way, you don't have to manage versions in each of the module that talks to the db

Comment: @ZohaibAmir What you mean is that only one separate module(suppose this module is named A) adds the upgrade code when creating the database, and the others(suppose these modules are named Bs) are not added？Must i change the version in `@Database` annotation of database in Bs or just remove version? And how can i get db in Bs, if the code get the db in A  is `AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class, "database-name").addMigrations(migration1_2, migration2_3).build();`?

Comment: Using two database objects in one app? Isn't it very expensive? "Each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances within a single process." ([source](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#database))